# zend rest route messing up routing for default controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-rest, zend-rest-route

I have implemented a RESTful service by extending the Zend_Rest_Controller. The service works great. I have only one controller that actually has RESTful behavior. So I added the rest route for just that controller in the bootstrap.

```
protected function _initRestRoute()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController, array() , array('default' =>     array('MyserviceController')));
    $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);

}
```

problem starts when I run my portal zend app. The links in the layout for the index controller miss out on the action parameter when I construct the URL. For example the link on the index layout for a action homepage in the network controller is as follows.

```
$this->url(array('controller'=>'network','action'=>'homepage','module'=>'default'));
```

this should return "localhost/projectname/public/network/homepage" instead it returns "localhost/projectname/public/network". This behavior is only when the layout is loaded by the default controller i.e. IndexController. The routing problem vanishes if I remove the zend rest route from the bootstrap. As long as I am mentioning what controller the rest request has to route to it should not be a problem right. But this is affecting the default controller routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common issue and usually resolved with something like:

```
$this->url(array('controller'=>'network','action'=>'homepage','module'=>'default'), 'default');
```

or:

```
$this->url(array('controller'=>'network','action'=>'homepage','module'=>'default'), NULL, TRUE);
```

might work.

if your `'module'=>'default'` is the default controllers directory at`/application/controllers` you can omit the module option from the route.

Here is the whole url method note the comments for the reset option.

```
/**
     * Generates an url given the name of a route.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param  array $urlOptions Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
     * @param  mixed $name The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
     * @param  bool $reset Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
     * @return string Url for the link href attribute.
     */
    public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
    }
```